# New IsWiX Setup Project fails to build - undefined preprocessor variable

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-project, wix3.7, iswix

I am attempting to use WiX Toolset to create a deployment project. I am using Visual Studio.NET 2010 SP1, WiX 3.7, and IsWix 2.0.13013.4.  I am using .NET framework 4.0.

I created the directory structure provided below.

```
C:\Projects\ExcelXLL\Installer

C:\Projects\ExcelXLL\Installer\Deploy
```

I added an IsWix Setup Project under the Installer directory in the path `C:\Projects\ExcelXLL\Installer\ExcelXLL64Deploy`.

If I attempt to compile the setup project, I get the exception:

> Error 1   Undefined preprocessor variable
>   '$(var.ExcelXLL64DeployMM.TargetPath)'.   C:\Projects\ExcelXLL\Installer\ExcelXLL64Deploy\Code\Features.wxs   16  1   ExcelXLL64Deploy

What am I doing wrong or is there an issue with either IsWix or Wix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IsWiX project templates assume you'll create an MSI project called Foo and a MSM project called FooMM.  These assumptions are meant to automate and template as much as possible and can be changed to your tastes.

After creating the projects, you then add a reference from Foo to FooMM.  This then resolves $(var.FooMM.TargetPath).

You can watch a short, silent walkthrough video [here](http://blog.iswix.com/2013/01/iswix-20130134-released.html).

If you have additional questions, feel free to email me.  And thanks for using IsWiX. :)

Update:  We now have [tutorials](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did not realize that the project name had a naming convention and was attempting to name it with a different name.

Comment: Yes, it was my attempt at a convention over configuration to make initial project setup as painless as possible.

Comment: Adding the project-reference to the setup-project was a good hint (I got an "Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)'" error

Comment: I've added a link to some new tutorials that we have.